# Why is this question still considered opinion-based?

Tags: support

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991930/can-i-use-custom-widgets-as-the-rows-of-a-grid-layout) that I posted was closed as opinion-based.

Why?  It might have been too broad in its original form, but in its current form it's really just asking "is X possible," which is clearly not opinion-based: either it's possible or it's not.  I did check that there was a re-open vote and that it was closed by all three reviewers, so based on [the advice on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) I'm posting here.  (The "reopen-request" tag does not exist, though.)

Comment: I'm not qualified in answering why it was closed, but maybe it's that there are too many possible solutions. If you try giving a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) with where you get stuck using a custom widget people might be able to help / re-open

Comment: Based on the question as it is written now, I think this is a red flag: *"How can I acheive this with QT?"*. It is a red flag because there is no code with it. You are effectively asking for someone to write you a tutorial (on-site), or you are asking for someone to provide you with a reference to a tutorial (off-site). Often times, when the reason is "write me an on-site tutorial", the close reason is *"Too Broad"*.

Comment: Questions are not re-opened for the sole purpose of closing them for a different reason. To do so requires 10 different votes, or a moderator. It's not reasonable for 10 different people to coordinate to do that. Thus, even if your question is no longer opinion based, but is off-topic for a different reason, the banner will remain as saying that it is opinion based, until it is reopened by people who feel it should actually be open. There have been multiple feature requests for SE to show all the reasons selected and/or show new reasons, but there's no indication that such will be implemented.

Comment: @2012rcampion https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jww I am not asking for a tutorial, I am asking for a short answer like "you cannot" or "use a QTableView."

Comment: @Makyen That answers my question.  If you could put your comment into an answer so I can mark the question as answered I would appreciate it.

Comment: @RChampion - You've kind of tried both ends of the spectrum. You asked a "Is it possible" question (kind of like a 0 on the scale), and a "How do I do it" (kind of like a 100 on the scale). The middle is the place to be. Show some code, like your custom cell or custom button that lays over the cell, and state where you are having trouble.

Comment: @2012rcampion I added an expanded answer. I didn't initially add it as an answer because I wasn't certain it was the information you were looking for, and also figured there was probably a duplicate question for that answer somewhere. But, I didn't find a duplicate.

Comment: So that you know: Each question only gets one entry-by-edit into the Reopen Queue. If you edit your question again, you will need to find another way to get it into the Reopen Queue (basically, someone will have to vote to reopen in order for it to be put in the Reopen Queue again). That means you'll need to get at least one person to review it for reopening after your edit. Having that happen can end up being difficult. Leaving a comment here might be sufficient.

Comment: @jww My reason for asking the question is that I want to know which direction I am heading before I start. I could create the custom widget and the answer (I know now) will be, "you can't get this to work."  Or I could manually repeat the code for each row and show that, in which case the answer would (hopefully) be "you should have just done XYZ and saved yourself a lot of time."  My hope was that someone with QT experience would be able to quickly see "oh, this is an obvious use-case for the UVW pattern" and set me off in the right direction.

Comment: @jww I don't think this is a case of two extremes, I think my question is just wrong for stackexchange.  The question I want to ask is "how can I approach this problem," while good questions are "fix this thing that doesn't work."

Comment: @2012rcampion, While there's are a lot of debugging questions on SO, "how do I do [this]" can be a good question. In fact, some of the best questions on SO are "how do I do [this]". However, [this] needs to be *very* narrow and quite well defined/constrained. Even something like "How can I approach [this] problem" *might* be a reasonable question, but that wording implies you think there are multiple, non-trivial, ways of doing [this]. Once that's the case, it often strays into opinion. The more clearly/narrowly you define [this] and the criteria for success, the less opinionated it becomes.

Comment: @Makyen I don't even know if there are zero, one, or more good ways of doing what I'm trying to do, so I don't think I *can* write a good question.  The real problem I'm encountering is that stackoverflow's goal is "having the best answers," not "answering people's questions."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions are, usually<sup>1</sup>, not re-opened for the sole purpose of closing them for a different reason. To do so requires 10 different votes, or a moderator. It's not reasonable for 10 people to coordinate to do that. Thus, even if your question is no longer opinion based, but is off-topic for a different reason, the banner will remain as saying that it's opinion based, until it is reopened by people who feel it should actually be open.

I understand and agree that the situation is frustrating. It makes the process of editing a question into being on-topic more difficult for the question author than it would be if the question author was given more information about what close reasons the close-voters felt applied, particularly if the question has changed sufficiently such that completely different reasons apply (i.e. what reasons the "Leave Closed" voters in the reopen queue felt applied; currently they don't select a specific reason).

There have been multiple feature requests for various ways by which SE might improve how this information is presented to question authors, including things like allowing close-voters to select all the reasons they feel apply, showing all the reasons selected by the five close-voters<sup>2</sup> and/or show new reasons that people add or specify in the reopen queue<sup>3</sup>, but there's been no indication that anything will be implemented.

---

1. I've seen it happen a very few times, but only to reopen a question in order to close it as a duplicate, which can take as few as 6 votes (5 to reopen and 1 gold-tag-badge holder to close as duplicate). Even in that situation, it's very rare.
2. Currently only one of the highest voted reasons, or, in some cases, the two reasons with the highest votes are shown in the banner.
3. Currently, there's no methodology to specify reasons beyond the initial close-votes. Reasons are not specified for a "Leave Closed" action in the Reopen Queue.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, you really went above and beyond!  I just needed something like "your question is also off-topic, that's why it wasn't reopened."